# Scopes on my sign in with google include request to see and download contacts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I've created an app with sign in with google functionality. In the Google Cloud console I've set up my OAuth consent screen, attempting to request no scopes other than whats necessary. However, when I go through the login process the app is requesting to see and download my contacts.

The requests to see and download contacts:

[image: Request to see and download contacts]
[image: Details of request]

Configuration in Google Cloud console:

[image]

This is the only selected scope when I go to "add or remove scopes":

[image]

Here are the relevant terraform resources in my codebase:

```
# Creates an Identity Platform config.
# Also enables Firebase Authentication with Identity Platform in the project if not.
resource "google_identity_platform_config" "auth" {
  provider = google-beta.user_project_override
  project  = var.project_id

  # If environment is prod, also add var.prod_domain to authorized_domains
  authorized_domains = concat(
    ["${var.project_id}.firebaseapp.com", "${var.project_id}.web.app"],
    var.environment == "prod" ? [var.prod_domain] : []
  )

  # For example, you can configure to auto-delete Anonymous users.
  # autodelete_anonymous_users = true
}

# Adds more configurations, like for the email/password sign-in provider.
resource "google_identity_platform_project_default_config" "auth" {
  provider = google-beta.user_project_override
  project  = var.project_id
  sign_in {
    allow_duplicate_emails = false
    # anonymous {
    #   enabled = false
    # }
    email {
      enabled           = true
      password_required = true
    }
  }
}

resource "google_identity_platform_default_supported_idp_config" "idp_config" {
  provider      = google-beta.user_project_override
  enabled       = true
  idp_id        = "google.com"
  client_id     = var.oauth_client_id
  client_secret = var.oauth_client_secret
  depends_on = [
    google_project_service.identitytoolkit,
  ]
}
```

However, I couldn't see any ways to configure the consent screen using terraform so configuring that was done via the Google Cloud UI.

What do I change to remove the request for contact information?

Comment: Edit your question and include your code your code is requesting scopes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @LindaLawton-DaImTo. I have added some of my code to the question. However, I'm unaware of a terraform resource that allows me to control requested scopes.